# Wordpress sites and Kinsta. Is Docker applicable?

Tags: wordpress, docker, kinsta

I've started trying to understand Docker. However, it would appear that Docker can only "deploy containers" to AWS and MS Azure. We deploy Wordpress sites to Kinsta.

With regard to Wordpress and Kinsta, is Docker useful at all?

Comment: Not your direct question, but Docker doesn't require a cloud provider.  It's very easy to run Docker on "bare metal", including your own laptop; there are at least three different good ways to run Docker on AWS; and both the "run Docker on a managed instance" and "run hosted Kubernetes" paths will work on most public-cloud IaaS providers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With regard to Wordpress and Kinsta, is Docker useful at all?

No.

Kinsta appears to offer fully-managed WordPress hosting, or "software as a service".  You get to use WordPress via their administrative console and hosting tools, but you personally do not directly install WordPress or the underlying database.

Docker is a packaging and distribution mechanism for software.  It's certainly common enough to install and deploy WordPress via Docker, but this isn't something you'd need to do with a SaaS service like Kinsta: they've already installed and deployed WordPress for you.

Answer (score 0):

Now it is. You can use [DevKinsta](https://kinsta.com/devkinsta/) locally to manage your WP sites. And DevKinsta uses Docker to build and deploy your site. Which is similar to what it does in production environments on GCP, from my understanding.

You can also deploy your WP website to Kinsta from GitHub or GitLab. For example, this document shows [how to deploy a WP site to Kinsta using GitLab CI/CD](https://kinsta.com/docs/gitlab-ci-cd/).

Furthermore, now Kinsta offers application hosting and database hosting. You can [use a Dockerfile to configure your app's deployment to Kinsta](https://kinsta.com/docs/dockerfiles/).